# Button got stuck

Tags: android, button

I am creating an app which has a button which performs some functions on the data.

It is working well for some data but for some data when the button is pressed the button is getting stuck as in the button remains in the pressed state.

What are the reasons for a button remain in pressed state?

Comment: You possibly are doing infinite operation `onClick()`

Comment: Can you try to do a Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example? http://sscce.org

Comment: Without some code or something it would be hard to diagnose this.  However, I would look at 2 things: 1. is it a toggle button? 2. Is an exception being thrown somewhere or an infinite loop that is preventing the button from being returned to it's unpressed state?

Comment: It is a 600 lines of code inside the button click so did not potst here. It is not a toggle button. No exception is being thrown anywhere, how to know exaclty what is preventing the button from becoming unpressed? How to know whther it is going through an infinite loop?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the end of the method and run it in a debugger?  Or log something out at the end of the function...if you prefer  "printf" style debugging.

Comment: 600 lines of code is usually too much for an on click, they will usually not return in a timely manner. As for going through an infinite loop, there is no real way to see, unless you dont have a condition to break out of that loop, or your condition isnever called.

Comment: I may be having a similar problem.  My symptoms are that I click the button, it brings up an activity, then I try clicking the button again, but it doesn't seem to register.  However, if I give something else focus, like a text edit, the button clicks.  If I clicked the button 10 times, it performs the action 10 times.  It registers each touch event as I make them, but doesn't call onClick until focus goes away.  Plus, I have one button each for several rows in a list, but only the first two seem to display this behavior, and neither break the cycle.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: If anybody else ever has the same problem as I, I figured out what it was: for some reason, when I clicked a button to start an activity, if the sub-activity finish()ed with the keyboard showing, my buttons got stuck.  Before calling finish(), I called `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`
and `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mContent.getWindowToken(), 0);`, where mContent is the view that has focus/is making the keyboard stick around.  My buttons stopped sticking.  Also, this problem seemed version dependent (2.3.6).

Answer (score 1):

The only time that the button resumes from a pressed state is when all the code on the listener is run. You are most likely doing calculation intensive work in the button (in the main thread). If this is so if you click anywhere else in the application you should see an ANR (application not responding) message that closes the application.
Another reason would be that you switch the state manually and forget to cancel it on your on touch listener (if you have one)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UApv-ZMJ51g

Comment: Yes I am getting ANR. Now what should i do??

Comment: If you are getting an ANR then that means that you are running too long of an operation (calculation or whatever) inside the main thread. You need to work it into an async task to run it outside the main thread, look up updating my answer to add a youtube link, it should give you a bit of insight into UI interaction with other code.